# Статическая динамическая переменная. Работа с динамической переменной после освобождения памяти, занимаемой ею

Tags: c++, память, переменные

Два вопроса:

1. Корректно ли создавать динамическую переменную со спецификатором `static`?

   `static int *i = new int;` - верно?
2. Можно ли работать с дин.переменной после её удаления:

   ```
   int *i = new int;
   delete i;
   i = new int;
   ```

Comment: `i` в ваших примерах - обычный указатель. Он не назвается и никогда не назывался "динамической переменной". Ничего "динамического" в `i` нет. "Динамической переменной" можно назвать то, что вы выделяете при помощи `new`, но к `i` эта переменная никакого отношения не имеет. `i` просто указывает на эту "динамическую переменную", не более того. `delete i` ничего не делает с `i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Да, корректно, почему нет?
2. Да, можно. Причём во многих библиотеках примерно так делается.
   Вы удаляете не переменную `i`, а освобождаете память, на которую указывает указатель `i`, и после этого его можно заставить указывать на новую область памяти.

Comment: А возле какого ответа ставить галочку, если оба правильны?-_-

Comment: @АртурКлочко, какой больше нравится

Comment: А ладно, поставлю наугад

Answer (score 7):

Давайте кое-что проясним. `int *i` это переменная типа **указатель на int**. Когда вы пишете `delete i;` вы не удаляете переменную, вы удаляете то, на что она указывает. Другими словами так делать можно:

```
int *i = new int;
delete i;
i = new int;
```

Потому что вы работаете с переменной типа **указатель на int**, которая цела и невредима.

А так делать нельзя

```
int *i = new int;
delete i;
*i = 42;
```

Потому что вы работаете у переменной типа **int**, которая была удалена.

Теперь, когда мы это прояснили, автоматически все стало понятно и с первым вопросом. Да, так делать можно. Вы создали **статическую переменную типа указатель на инт**, и инициализировали её указателем на переменную типа **int**, которая находится в **динамической памяти**