# Использование указателя на динамическую переменную после её удаления

Tags: c++, указатели, память

У меня это почему-то работает (пользуюсь DevC++ 5.11):

```
int* a=new int(13);
cout<<a<<endl;    //0x635800
cout<<*a<<endl;   //13
delete a;
*a=123;
(*a)*=2;
cout<<a<<endl;    //0x635800
cout<<*a<<endl;   //246
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После освобождения ячейки памяти, на которую указывал **a**, судя по адресу, в неё же было добавлено новое значение, которое даже можно извлечь, умножить и результат поместить в ту же ячейку. Выводит то, что и ожидалось: 246.
Тут сказано, что "так делать нельзя": https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/564989/279581
Почему, если всё работает? Что же выполняет инструкция **delete a;**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Она просто **помечает память как свободную**.

А вы что подумали? :)

Так что вы просто пишете в незанятую память, читаете из нее. Все работает. Только вот никто не гарантирует, что эта память не будет затерта, перезаписана или что вы своей записью не обвалите сам диспетчер памяти, попав в служебные записи.

Неопределенное поведение - оно такое неопределенное....

Понимаете, вы можете перебегать дорогу на красный свет светофора. Можете переходить ее с завязанными глазами и заткнутыми ушами. И у вас это будет отлично получаться... до поры до времени.

И то, что после нескольких переходов вы остались живы и здоровы - является ли основанием говорить, что "на красный переходить можно, я проверял!"?

Answer (score 4):

C++ — взрослый язык. Он формулирует для вас правила, и следовать этим правилам — *ваша* обязанность. В отличие от других языков, C++ не будет проверять, следуете вы правилам или нет, он считает, что вы сами в состоянии это обеспечить.

Если вы следуете правилам, всё будет работать правильно. Если нет — никаких гарантий нет, может, будет, а может, нет, что угодно может пойти не так в любой момент. Но вы ж взрослый разработчик, сами всё понимаете?

---

Вот ответ Эрика Липперта (одного из бывших ведущих разработчиков языка C#) на аналогичный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/276994

Answer (score 2):

Поведение вашего кода формально **не определено**. Это значит, что произойти может что угодно. В том числе возможно, что код будет якобы "работать". То, что в вашем конкретном эксперименте код "работал", никак не противоречит тому факту, что так делать нельзя.