# Си: итерация через указатель

Tags: c, указатели

Прошу понять: я не профессиональный программист, занимаюсь этим в качестве хобби. Так что где ещё спрашивать, как не здесь.

Если в Си выделить под указатель несколько блоков памяти соответствующего размера,

```
int* pointer = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

то к ним можно обращаться на манер индекса в массиве:

```
pointer[3] = 10;
```

Как-то раз я решил попробовать, можно ли провести итерацию через указатель и подсчитать количество элементов в нём?

```
int i = 0;
while(pointer[i]) i++;
```

К моему удивлению, ошибки сегментации не произошло, и после прохождения выделенных блоков памяти цикл благополучно прервался. Подсчёт прошёл корректно. 
Нормально ли это или же просто совпадение? Практикуется ли такое? Или это такая защитная функция gcc от "экспериментаторов" вроде меня? Я помню, например, как в ВУЗовском учебнике "С/С++" авторы создавали целый двунаправленный список с указателями на прошлый и следующий элементы, которым присваивался NULL, чтобы указать, что дальше выделенных объектов нет.
Также ещё можно выделить блоков памяти на один больше нужного, и присвоить последнему NULL, и тогда при итерации цикл также будет безопасно прерываться. Но можно ли вообще вот так вслепую итерироваться по указателю, пусть у него и инициализированы все элементы?

Comment: "Нормально ли это или же просто совпадение?" - Вам повезло.

Comment: *"выделить под указатель несколько блоков памяти соответствующего размера"* - под указатель у вас выделяется только один блок `pointer` с автоматическим временем хранения. *"подсчитать количество элементов в нём"* - в нем нет никаких элементов, элементы есть хранятся в массиве, выделенном `malloc`, но узнать их количество нельзя. `while(pointer[i])` не считает элементы в массиве, а проверяет, является ли i-й элемент ненулевым. Так как содержимое массива не инициализировано, это будет являться неопределенным поведением еще даже до выхода за пределы массива.

Comment: Неопределенное поведение - оно такое неопределенное....

Понимаете, вы можете перебегать дорогу на красный свет светофора. Можете переходить ее с завязанными глазами и заткнутыми ушами. И у вас это будет отлично получаться... до поры до времени.

И то, что после нескольких переходов вы остались живы и здоровы - является ли основанием говорить, что "на красный переходить можно, я проверял!"?  [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764870/195342) разбирается похожий вопрос, с обращением "куда нельзя"...

Comment: @Igor Скорее **не** повезло...

Comment: Нулей в памяти много, так что ничего странного, что не упали  (*на всякий случай:* `while(p[i])` *это то же самое, что и:* `while(p[i] != 0)`)